# Choosing Intuit Development Framework

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am building a .Net C# application that would allow connection to Quickbooks Online.  I understand that in order to work with Intuit Anywhere the application must a SaaS.  Does that mean the application must be available in Intuit's App Center?  I want to build an application, but right now I do not have plans to make it available in the Intuit App Center.  If this is true, is my only option for developing to use Quickbooks SDK?  If yes, is there documentation and example .Net code available that talks about authentication/connectivity using SDK with Quickbooks Online.

Comment: The application does not need to be available on Appcenter. If you are building it just for your use, you will need to look at the SDK rather than IA because we don't support custom apps at this time in IA. Download the QB SDK from http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb.

Comment: The application will be for people/companies I support that use Quickbooks Online.  I will be providing a service to these people through the application I build.  Is my only option still SDK?

Comment: If you're SaaS (e.g. you charge your customers a recurring fee to allow your app to connect to their QuickBooks) then use Intuit Anywhere. Otherwise, use the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  If you answer as an actual 'answer' I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a Saas application due to the nature of the Intuit Anywhere model, but it does not have to be available on the Intuit Appcenter. Sounds like it is for the existing customers of your current service. In that case it is fine, its termed as "Connect to QuickBooks" only.

Follow the guidelines for publishing on Intuit Anywhere, the only difference is there is no marketing review or publishing of the app to the app center.

thanks
Jarred